# How can i make my spring boot app find my mysql jdbc jar?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm getting this error:  "*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*"

Here is the POM section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here is my application properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.datasource.name=demodb 
spring.datasource.username=root@localhost
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.database=mysql 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDial‌​ect
```

Here is the full stack trace:

https://gist.github.com/vt97john/f21c7a181fb7e4935a817e7aa84e20d1

Comment: Have u added spring-boot-starter-jdbc to your pom/gradle build file. Can u add the complete stacktrace here.

Comment: Yes on the pom.  I've added full trace above.

Comment: I can't see the version of mysql-connector-java here

Comment: Check the Maven dependencies and see if the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is inside your jars

Comment: I the jsar in my project is  mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar ... and it does contain com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to mention "Drivers" twice in your application.properties,it arises the conflict to which Driver it should inject. And you have mentioned it again in pom.xml. Mentioning DriverClassName once in application.properties is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Here is my entire pom: 
  https://gist.github.com/vt97john/4964ba129ce76f4417a8ca9cfcd7c07b